# Why, in general, are proofs of possession (POPs) "clearly" not sufficient for substantiating the knowledge of secret key (KOSK) assumption?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, attack

In [Ristenpart, Yilek - The Power of Proofs-of-Possession: Securing Multiparty Signatures against Rogue-Key Attacks](https://rist.tech.cornell.edu/papers/pkreg.pdf) they have the statement:

> In general, such proofs of possession (POPs) are clearly not sufficient for substantiating the KOSK assumption.

Can someone explain this to me? It seems reasonable to me that if someone can sign a message for a POP, they must know what the secret key is.

What does the KOSK require that a POP does not necessarily provide?

Can you give a simple example?

Is a POP alone sufficient to prevent rogue key attacks?

Comment: If you're delivered a smartcard with a provisioned keypair then you have access to use it but don't know the actual secret key bits

Comment: Does my answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70973/what-is-the-knowledge-of-secret-key-assumption-kosk) answer your question?